# Calculating probability?

Tags: probability

I am currently a first-year maths student so forgive me if this question is actually very simple! I've always had trouble with probability questions.

The question is as follows:
60% of students eat in the canteen (C) and 80% of students eat at home (H). If 5% of students eat only in the canteen, find the probability that a randomly selected student eats both at home and in the canteen.

I'm confused because in one line the question goes from stating that 60% eat in the canteen to 5% eat in the canteen, so I feel as though I'm missing something obvious. I think I have to calculate the intersect in order to answer the question but I could be mistaken.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is poorly worded.  The $60\%$ counts those who eat in the cafeteria at least sometimes.  That is, it counts those who only eat in the cafeteria ($5\%$) and those who sometimes eat in the cafeteria and sometimes eat at home.  Similarly for the $80\%$.

Comment: If you have two events $E_1$ and $E_2$ that are **not** mutually exclusive (meaning that the events can both happen) and if $p(E)$ is the probability of event $E$ occurring, then $p(E_1 ~\text{or} ~E_2 ~\text{occurring}) ~=~ p(E_1) + p(E_2) - p(E_1 ~\text{and} ~E_2 ~\text{both occurring}).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the easiest way is to draw a Venn Diagram of the situation

[image]

Where it is evident that

1. 5% eat ONLY and always in the canteen
2. 55% eat in the canteen but also at home, it depends: perhaps Canteen on Monday and Tuesday...then at home because of the Canteen's meal is very hard to digest
3. 25% eat only and always at home
4. 15% remaining eat somewhere else, in a pub or they do not eat (they go to the gym)

Comment: Thank you! That makes it much easier to visualise. So, how would I go about finding the probability of picking a student who eats both at home and in the canteen?